# Where are Video and Audio classes in Vaadin 14?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

The Vaadin Sampler shows demos for Video and Audio componets:

- https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-presentation/video
- https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-presentation/audio

We are building a Vaadin Flow component using Vaadin 14, yet I can't seem to find these components in the Vaadin API, and following the API links from the Sampler yields 404 errors.

Have these classes been dropped from Vaadin but not removed from the Sampler?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 2):

The sampler is based on Vaadin 8. You can find docs about the available replacements for Vaadin Flow here https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/upgrading/v8/5-components

Answer (score 0):

The videos for vaadin 14+ can be found on their [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/vaadinofficial/playlists) . I specifically recommend you check out the [Java web app using Vaadin 14+ tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quiQg9bgFs8&list=PLcRrh9hGNallPtT2VbUAsrWqvkQ-XE22h&ab_channel=vaadinofficial) by [Marcus](https://twitter.com/marcushellberg). It will guide you through the basics of Vaadin 14+ and also help you navigate further documentation for the components.

There is also a [Practical Vaadin book by Alejandro](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484271785) which is a very good resource for mastering the new Vaadin platform.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).